# How to convert Object value to array and add new value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, columnsorting

I would like to know how I can convert Object value to array and add value to this array.
For example:
I have object

```
const object = {
 names: "John"
}
```

How can I convert this names from string to array, like this

```
const namesFromApi = ['Ken', 'Ben', 'Joana', 'Fillip']

namesFromApi.map(el => {
object.names = [names, el]
})
```

And add new name to my new array from string value

Answer (score 2):

You mean this? Using the spread operator and square brackets to concatenate the names

```js
const object = {
 names: "John"
}
const namesFromApi = ['Ken', 'Ben', 'Joana', 'Fillip']

object.names = [object.names,...namesFromApi]

console.log(object)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a new array, you can use:

```
const object = {
    names: "John"
}
const newObj = [object.names];

const namesFromApi = ['Ken', 'Ben', 'Joana', 'Fillip'];
namesFromApi.forEach(el => {
newObj.push(el);
});
```

Comment: `forEach` is a better solution. `map` creates a new array.

Comment: Yes thats true, he wants that : "And add new name to my new array from string value". and I stated that in my response.

Comment: Yes, but you're not assigning the new array to anything.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, I've missed it